# Iterating column of a table in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to compare two columns of two differennt tables in access . I have writeen the following code in Vba but I am getting an error :

```
For Each Motor.a In Motor
  For Each Machine.b In Machine                                    
    If b = a Then
    Else
      MsgBox "Value= " & b
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Machine and Motor are both tables and ( a and b ) are columns in motor and machine respectively with text datatype . I get an error when I run this . How change should I make ?

Comment: What error and what line?

Comment: What's your definitions of 'Motor' and 'Machine'? does 'b = a' need to be qualified? Have you tried compiling the code?

Comment: Wait so even if Machine.b exists in table Motor.a, you are going to print it out for every record it doesn't match on? In this case if you have 5 values in both tables and the 5 Machines match the 5 motors, you will still display 20 message boxes. Am I reading that right?

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to handle this in a SQL solution?  This kind of problem seems suited towards it.

Comment: Sorry for replying late . In simple terms machine table has 500 records and motor has around 300 records and I want to display the names of motors which are new ( not in machine table )

Comment: The error that I get is that the compiler cannot interpret motor.a which is a field 'a' in motor table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, you need to read the table data into a RecordSet before you can process it.
I'd suggest starting again with code that looks something like...

```
Sub test()
    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim R As DAO.Recordset

    Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Set R = DB.OpenRecordset("Motor", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

    R.MoveFirst
    Debug.Print R.Fields("a").Value
    Debug.Print R!a

    R.Close
    Set R = Nothing
    Set DB = Nothing

End Sub
```